# In python, how to fix the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '***' problem?

Tags: python, import, package

In python, I have a ABC.pye file which is encrypted by the package "sourcedefender".

To obtain the Function I need in the ABC.pye file, I use the following:

```
pip install sourcedefender
import sourcedefender
from ABC import Function
```

But then occurs the error,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\OPAC\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-7-8e557d63fc80>", line 1, in <module>
    from ABC import Function
  File "C:\Users\OPAC\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PyCharm 2020.1.2\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_import_hook.py", line 21, in do_import
    module = self._system_import(name, *args, **kwargs)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ABC'
```

Is it because the file is not in the right folder?

I put the file in the path "C:\Users\OPAC\PycharmProjects\untitled",
is it the correct path to put the ABC.pye?

Please tell me how to solve the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '***' problem.

Thank you very much

Comment: What exactly does your directory structure look like and where are you typing those imports in?

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your python file in the lib folder in your python directory as that is where the standard library is installed, and i'm pretty sure the interpreter checks that folder for modules with the same name as your import.